# Angular 2 : show second div on 1st div click and first div on second click

Tags: angular

I have 2 divs. I want to show 2nd div on 1st div click and show 1st div on 2nd div click. By default , 1st div should be shown.

```js
backClick:boolean ;

ngOnInit() {
   this.backClick = true;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="backclick==true">
<span (click)="help_screen=true">Click</span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="help_screen==true">
<span (click) = "backclick=true">Back</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: when you click the 2nd div, do you need to hide it and show the 1st div?

Comment: exactly. show 1st div on clicking on 2nd div and hide 2nd div and vice versa.

Comment: posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
backClick = true;

onToggle():void{
     this.backClick = !this.backClick;
}
```

You can set the initial value when you declare the value. You don't need to declare it in ngOnInit if you want. 
And in your template

```
<div *ngIf="backClick">
<span (click)="onToggle()">Click</span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!backClick">
<span (click) = "onToggle()">Back</span>
</div>
```

If backclick is true, it shows the 1st div, otherwise, hide it and shows the 2nd div.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, It's not working.. I get only `back` text div . I want `Click` text div to be appeared by default. when I click on back then nothing happens. I did console.log and i get true , false , true , false. but not showing and disappearing div.

Comment: @Rishi I updated my answer. try to set the backClick to true.

Comment: just one correction sir.. there are 2 variables. one with Captial C in backClick and 2nd is small c in backclick. due to that I stuck for 2 hours. :(

Comment: sorry about that. I will update my answer. yes that "error" can happen to anyone lol

Comment: No problem. Glad to help